# How to find max value with shift and condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `Dataframe` like this:

```
Index A
0     3
1     2
2     5
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     7
7     3
8     1
```

And i need to go with the shift, taking 5 pieces and so that the maximum is in the center of them.

Result:

```
Index A   Res
0     3    0
1     2    0
2     5    5
3     4    0
4     1    0
5     2    0
6     7    7
7     3    0
8     1    0
```

How can i implement this using pandas methods?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try: `df.rolling(5, center=True)['A'].max().where(lambda x: x == df['A']).fillna(0).astype(int)`?

Comment: @Corralien Sorry if I didn't describe the task well, but your code is perfect for me.

Comment: Check the @mozway's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with the `center=True` and `step=5` parameters:

```
N = 5

df.loc[N//2::N, 'Res'] = (df['A'].rolling(N, center=True, min_periods=1, step=N)
                          .max().values
                         )
```

Output:

```
   Index  A  Res
0      0  3  NaN
1      1  2  NaN
2      2  5  5.0
3      3  4  NaN
4      4  1  NaN
5      5  2  NaN
6      6  7  NaN
7      7  3  7.0
8      8  1  NaN
```

If you want the `0`s either pre-fill the columns with them (`df['Res'] = 0`) or use @Corralien's approach from comments with a mask:

```
df['Res'] = (df.rolling(5, center=True, min_periods=1)['A'].max()
               .where(lambda x: x == df['A'], 0).convert_dtypes()
            )
```

Output:

```
   Index  A  Res
0      0  3    0
1      1  2    0
2      2  5    5
3      3  4    0
4      4  1    0
5      5  2    0
6      6  7    7
7      7  3    0
8      8  1    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, сan you recommend what to read for a good understanding of all the functions of Pandas? documentation?)

Comment: Yes, the documentation is very good, that's my primary source of information ;)

Answer (score 1):

To implement this using pandas, you can use the rolling method to get a sliding window of size 5 for the column 'A'. Then, you can use the apply method to check if the center of the window (i.e., the third element) is the maximum in that window. If it is, you'll set the value to be the center value; otherwise, you'll set it to 0. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to check if the center is the max value
def check_center_max(window):
    center_idx = len(window) // 2
    if window[center_idx] == max(window):
        return window[center_idx]
    return 0

# Apply the function using rolling window of size 5
df['Res'] = df['A'].rolling(window=5, center=True).apply(check_center_max, raw=True).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```